# jQuery Datastore best practice?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i am working on a simple demo.

- The user can submit a form via jquery.post
- The view get's refresht an loads new data via jquery.get from the backend
  *The user can select a date to load a different record via jquery.get from the backend.

**The challenge**
How to manage the data and rendering in the client? I would like to communicate via json only. That's why i need some kind of jquery datastore (create, read, update, delete) and a render/update method for my view. I saw a similar concept at ExtJS and I really would like to have something like that in jquery.

**Looking for some best practices.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) with jquery...Backbone is the best tool to establish a mock model (or database) in client side

---

A fairly good example can be found here: http://ryandotsmith.heroku.com/2010/10/a-backbone-js-demo-app-sinatra-backend.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JavascriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/). They have a good demo http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#&who=getstarted